# ¿Cómo hacer que la animación del hamburguer menu salga desde el botón y no desde el centro?

Tags: html, css, animación

Tengo un header hecho en mobile first, pero al momento de abrir el hamburguer menu, la animación aparece desde el centro y no desde el botón, el código lo intenté con `clip-path`, pero no encuentro la manera que la animación salga desde el botón.

**Adjunto mi propuesta para que sea más entendible**

```js
mostrarNav = () => {
  document
    .getElementsByClassName("header__navigation__hamburguer")[0]
    .classList.toggle("active");
};
```

```css
/* FONTS */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Crimson+Pro:wght@200&family=Lora:wght@500;700&family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');
/* VARIABLES */
/* FUNCTIONS*/
/* GLOBAL RESETS */
* {
    box-sizing : border-box;
    margin     : 0;
    padding    : 0;
}

html {
    font-size : 62.5%;
}

body {
    background-color : #181719;
}

a {
    text-decoration : none;
}

ul {
    list-style : none;
}

/* HEADING STYLES */
h1 {
    color       : #FFFFFF;
    font-family : 'Crimson Pro', serif;
    font-size   : 1.4rem;
    font-weight : 200;
}

h2 {
    color       : #FFFFFF;
    font-family : 'Lora', serif;
    font-size   : 3.6rem;
    font-weight : 500;
}

h3 {
    color       : #FFFFFF;
    font-family : 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size   : 1.2rem;
    font-weight : 500;
}

h4 {
    color       : #FFFFFF;
    font-family : 'Lora', serif;
    font-size   : 1.8rem;
    font-weight : 700;
}

h5 {
    color       : #A9A9A9;
    font-family : 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size   : 1.4rem;
    font-weight : 500;
}

.container {
    margin    : 0 auto;
    max-width : 37.5rem;
    width     : 90%;
}

/* HEADER */
/* HEADER */
.header {
    padding-top : 1.9rem;
}

.header__menu__container {
    align-items     : center;
    justify-content : space-between;
    display         : flex;
}

.header__menu__container h1 {
    border         : 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    padding        : 0.8rem;
    text-transform : uppercase;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer {
    align-items : center;
    cursor      : pointer;
    display     : flex;
    position    : relative;
    z-index     : 2;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer span {
    background-color : #FFFFFF;
    display          : block;
    height           : 0.3rem;
    margin-bottom    : 0.3rem;
    position         : relative;
    transition       : all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    width            : 3rem;
    z-index          : 99;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer__menu {
    background-color : red;
    clip-path        : circle(10%);
    height           : 100%;
    left             : 0;
    opacity          : 0;
    position         : absolute;
    top              : 0;
    transition       : all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    visibility       : hidden;
    width            : 100%;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer.active + .header__navigation__hamburguer__menu {
    clip-path  : circle(100%);
    opacity    : 1;
    visibility : visible;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__links {
    position   : absolute;
    top        : 50%;
    left       : 50%;
    transform  : translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align : center;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link {
    margin-bottom : 2rem;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link a {
    color          : #FFFFFF;
    font-family    : 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size      : 1.8rem;
    font-weight    : 500;
    border-bottom  : 2px solid transparent;
    color          : #FFFFFF;
    padding-bottom : 0.6rem;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link a:hover {
    color          : #FFFFFF;
    font-family    : 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size      : 1.8rem;
    font-weight    : 700;
    border-bottom  : 2px solid white;
    padding-bottom : 0.6rem;
    transition     : all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.line {
    fill         : none;
    stroke       : #FFFFFF;
    stroke-width : 6;
    transition   : stroke-dasharray 600ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1), stroke-dashoffset 600ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

.line1 {
    stroke-dasharray : 60 207;
    stroke-width     : 6;
}

.line2 {
    stroke-dasharray : 60 60;
    stroke-width     : 6;
}

.line3 {
    stroke-dasharray : 60 207;
    stroke-width     : 6;
}

.active .line1 {
    stroke-dasharray  : 90 207;
    stroke-dashoffset : -134;
    stroke-width      : 6;
}

.active .line2 {
    stroke-dasharray  : 1 60;
    stroke-dashoffset : -30;
    stroke-width      : 6;
}

.active .line3 {
    stroke-dasharray  : 90 207;
    stroke-dashoffset : -134;
    stroke-width      : 6;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="header__container container">
    <div class="header__menu__container">
      <h1>This Interior</h1>
      <div class="header__navigation">
        <div class="header__navigation__hamburguer " onclick="mostrarNav()">
          <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
            <path class="line line1" d="M 20,29.000046 H 80.000231 C 80.000231,29.000046 94.498839,28.817352 94.532987,66.711331 94.543142,77.980673 90.966081,81.670246 85.259173,81.668997 79.552261,81.667751 75.000211,74.999942 75.000211,74.999942 L 25.000021,25.000058" />
            <path class="line line2" d="M 20,50 H 80" />
            <path class="line line3" d="M 20,70.999954 H 80.000231 C 80.000231,70.999954 94.498839,71.182648 94.532987,33.288669 94.543142,22.019327 90.966081,18.329754 85.259173,18.331003 79.552261,18.332249 75.000211,25.000058 75.000211,25.000058 L 25.000021,74.999942" />
          </svg>
        </div>
        <nav class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu">
          <ul class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__links">
            <li class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link">
              <a class="link-social" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link">
              <a class="link-social" href="#">Collection</a>
            </li>
            <li class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link">
              <a class="link-social" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link">
              <a class="link-social" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En `CSS` tenemos que:

- [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path):

  Para formula `circle()` podemos indicar `<shape-radius> at  <position>`, donde `position` son las coordenadas donde centrar el circulo
- [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/calc()):

  Nos permite realizar operaciones matemáticas entre distintas unidades de medida.

Dado que el menú esta centrado al ancho y alto del documento y el botón esta ubicado a la derecha dentro de la barra de menú, la cual tiene un ancho específico, lo que podemos hacer es calcular las coordenadas (`x, y`) donde se va a posicionar el botón.

Para calcular la coordenada `x` (*horizontal*) tenemos que:

- El centro horizontal esta a exactamente `50%` del documento
- Ademas tenemos que sumar la mitad del ancho de la barra de menú, es decir, `(37.5rem / 2)`
- Y finalmente restar la mitad del ancho del botón de hamburgesa, es decir, `(40px / 2)`

Para la coordenada `y` (*vertical*) tenemos que:

- Tiene que estar en el borde superior, es decir, `0%`
- Hay que sumar el margen de separación del `header`, es decir, `1.9rem`
- Y la mitad del alto del botón de hamburguesa, es decir, `(40px / 2)`

#### Ejemplo:

```js
mostrarNav = () => {
  document
    .getElementsByClassName("header__navigation__hamburguer")[0]
    .classList.toggle("active");
};
```

```css
/* FONTS */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Crimson+Pro:wght@200&family=Lora:wght@500;700&family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');
/* VARIABLES */
/* FUNCTIONS*/
/* GLOBAL RESETS */
* {
    box-sizing : border-box;
    margin     : 0;
    padding    : 0;
}

html {
    font-size : 62.5%;
}

body {
    background-color : #181719;
}

a {
    text-decoration : none;
}

ul {
    list-style : none;
}

/* HEADING STYLES */
h1 {
    color       : #FFFFFF;
    font-family : 'Crimson Pro', serif;
    font-size   : 1.4rem;
    font-weight : 200;
}

h2 {
    color       : #FFFFFF;
    font-family : 'Lora', serif;
    font-size   : 3.6rem;
    font-weight : 500;
}

h3 {
    color       : #FFFFFF;
    font-family : 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size   : 1.2rem;
    font-weight : 500;
}

h4 {
    color       : #FFFFFF;
    font-family : 'Lora', serif;
    font-size   : 1.8rem;
    font-weight : 700;
}

h5 {
    color       : #A9A9A9;
    font-family : 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size   : 1.4rem;
    font-weight : 500;
}

.container {
    margin    : 0 auto;
    max-width : 37.5rem;
    width     : 90%;
}

/* HEADER */
/* HEADER */
.header {
    padding-top : 1.9rem;
}

.header__menu__container {
    align-items     : center;
    justify-content : space-between;
    display         : flex;
}

.header__menu__container h1 {
    border         : 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    padding        : 0.8rem;
    text-transform : uppercase;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer {
    align-items : center;
    cursor      : pointer;
    display     : flex;
    position    : relative;
    z-index     : 2;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer span {
    background-color : #FFFFFF;
    display          : block;
    height           : 0.3rem;
    margin-bottom    : 0.3rem;
    position         : relative;
    transition       : all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    width            : 3rem;
    z-index          : 99;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer__menu {
    background-color : red;
    clip-path        : circle(40px at calc(50% + (37.5rem / 2) - (40px / 2)) calc(0% + 1.9rem + (40px / 2)));
    height           : 100%;
    left             : 0;
    opacity          : 0;
    position         : absolute;
    top              : 0;
    transition       : all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    visibility       : hidden;
    width            : 100%;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer.active + .header__navigation__hamburguer__menu {
    clip-path  : circle(100%);
    opacity    : 1;
    visibility : visible;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__links {
    position   : absolute;
    top        : 50%;
    left       : 50%;
    transform  : translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align : center;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link {
    margin-bottom : 2rem;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link a {
    color          : #FFFFFF;
    font-family    : 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size      : 1.8rem;
    font-weight    : 500;
    border-bottom  : 2px solid transparent;
    color          : #FFFFFF;
    padding-bottom : 0.6rem;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link a:hover {
    color          : #FFFFFF;
    font-family    : 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size      : 1.8rem;
    font-weight    : 700;
    border-bottom  : 2px solid white;
    padding-bottom : 0.6rem;
    transition     : all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.line {
    fill         : none;
    stroke       : #FFFFFF;
    stroke-width : 6;
    transition   : stroke-dasharray 600ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1), stroke-dashoffset 600ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

.line1 {
    stroke-dasharray : 60 207;
    stroke-width     : 6;
}

.line2 {
    stroke-dasharray : 60 60;
    stroke-width     : 6;
}

.line3 {
    stroke-dasharray : 60 207;
    stroke-width     : 6;
}

.active .line1 {
    stroke-dasharray  : 90 207;
    stroke-dashoffset : -134;
    stroke-width      : 6;
}

.active .line2 {
    stroke-dasharray  : 1 60;
    stroke-dashoffset : -30;
    stroke-width      : 6;
}

.active .line3 {
    stroke-dasharray  : 90 207;
    stroke-dashoffset : -134;
    stroke-width      : 6;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="header__container container">
    <div class="header__menu__container">
      <h1>This Interior</h1>
      <div class="header__navigation">
        <div class="header__navigation__hamburguer " onclick="mostrarNav()">
          <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
            <path class="line line1" d="M 20,29.000046 H 80.000231 C 80.000231,29.000046 94.498839,28.817352 94.532987,66.711331 94.543142,77.980673 90.966081,81.670246 85.259173,81.668997 79.552261,81.667751 75.000211,74.999942 75.000211,74.999942 L 25.000021,25.000058" />
            <path class="line line2" d="M 20,50 H 80" />
            <path class="line line3" d="M 20,70.999954 H 80.000231 C 80.000231,70.999954 94.498839,71.182648 94.532987,33.288669 94.543142,22.019327 90.966081,18.329754 85.259173,18.331003 79.552261,18.332249 75.000211,25.000058 75.000211,25.000058 L 25.000021,74.999942" />
          </svg>
        </div>
        <nav class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu">
          <ul class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__links">
            <li class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link">
              <a class="link-social" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link">
              <a class="link-social" href="#">Collection</a>
            </li>
            <li class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link">
              <a class="link-social" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link">
              <a class="link-social" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, muy acertada tu respuesta con la explicación. Saludos.